# REST: Best way to deal with secrets in DELETE

Tags: rest, security

I need to use a sensitive value as primary identifier in a REST Api.

This would be identified as:
`DELETE /api/sometoken/<sensitiveid>`

Since sensitive data should not be included in URLs, I wonder what the best option is.

### Sensitive ID in body

Would it be a valid solution to set the id as json in the body?
This would result in `DELETE /api/sometoken` with body `{ "id": "<sensitiveid>" }`

I am not sure if this is ok, since `DELETE` does not directly reference an entity by url.

### Abuse POST

Alternatively, I could use `POST` instead of `DELETE`, and contain the information about delete in the body or url. I assume this would be even worse.

### Abstract ID

This most complex solution would probably be using a different id.
When using `GET`, to lookup the all sensitive ids for my subscription and then `DELETE` the abstract id.

### Hashed ID

I thought of making an sha-256 hash and taking the first n characters to id identify the sensitive token.

`DELETE /api/sometoken/<hashofsensitiveid>`

Comment: https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post

Comment: You can send the sensitive id in the entity body of the DELETE request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10015724/1802536

Comment: Using a non-sensitive id in your URLs sound like a smart way to deal with this. A hash especially sounds smart.

Answer (score 0):

Putting secrets in the body part of the request is usually a good idea, but there might be issues for GET and PUT requests: [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

If it is sensitive and should not appear in some web server or traffic logs - make it simply a header.

Comment: The top answer there is wrong, you should not use bodies with `DELETE` requests.